# Fetch HTML Service Values by ID

Tags: google-apps-script

In the sample code:

HTML (Index):

```
<form>
<br><br>
Name:
<br>
<input type="text" name="name">
<br><br>
Comments:
<br>
<input type="text" id="comments">
<br><br>
<input type="button" id="button" value="Submit Info" onclick="google.script.run
        .testFunction(this.form)">
</form>
```

Code:

```
function doGet() {//Creates the webpage
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index')//From the GUI file.
      .evaluate()
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
}

function testFunction(form){
  Logger.log(form.name);//Works when using the 'name' of the element.
  Logger.log(form.comments);//Does not work when using the 'ID'. 
}
```

Why does a value get returned when adding the 'Name' of the HTML value, but not the 'ID'? If I want to get the value by ID, how would I do this instead? I've tried:

```
form.getElementById("comments");
```

But this just throws me an error, and to be honest I'm out of ideas after that.

Note: It's completely acceptable to me to use the 'name' field, as I have been doing, I'm just curious as I'm brushing up on my HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what Google is doing behind the scenes is extracting the `form` out as a HTML form and sending it back to the server. HTML forms use the `name` attribute to store all their name value pairs when sent back to the server. So if this was a get request for this form:

```
<form>
  <input type="text" name="field1" value="value1"/>
  <input type="text" name="field2" value="value2"/>
</form>
```

it would look something like `?field1=value1&field2=value2`.

So on the server side in your Code.gs you are basically getting this back as an object (not a DOM object, which is why your `form.getElementById("comments");` won't work).

Either way, the standard with `<input>` tags is to use the `name` attribute, so you should be sticking with that. The `id` attribute should really only be used if you need to look up a value in your client side javascript.